How does openEO aggregate_spatial() process works?
I am trying to do aggregates statistics for 5 geometries in blocks object.
mean_ndvi = p$aggregate_spatial(
  data = cloud_free,
  geometries = blocks,
  reducer = p$mean 
)

mean_ndvi_json = p$save_result(data = mean_ndvi, format = "JSON")
job = create_job(graph = mean_ndvi_json, title = "mean_ndvi_json")

start_job(job = job)

I tried to pass blocks object to the geometries argument as a sf object and as a vector data cube. In both instance a get this error after starting a job:

HTTP 400 Bad Request.
SERVER-ERROR: The value passed for parameter 'geometries' in process 'aggregate_spatial' is invalid: Invalid type: <class 'list'> ...

I would appreciate it very much if someone could help me to fix it.

Hard to help without reproducible example. Have you checked whether your object blocks is actually a list?
